# Python 3.3 Button hiding coding doesnt work

Tags: button, python-3.x

In my game after pressing the start button I wanted to hide the button to stop the user from pressing the start button again and making more bubbles appear. I tried to make a variable equal to 0. Then every time the start button was clicked the value would go up by 1. If the value was 2 then the start button would disappear or become inactive. By trying to add this 'hiding button code' its only showing one bubble on my screen when the start button is clicked. Oh and the started button doesn't hide... ._.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random
    import tkinter as tk
    # Message box for score to tell user if they have won or lost
    from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo



    class BubbleFrame:


        def __init__(self, root, name):
            self.name = name
            root.title("Math Bubbles")
            self.bubbles = {} # this will hold bubbles ids, positions and velocities
            self.score = 0
            self.buttonclick = 0 # Newly added in attempt to hide button
            Button(root, text="Start", width=8, bg="Pink", command=self.make_bubbles).pack() # This button starts the game, making the bubbles move across the screen
            Button(root, text="Quit", width=8, bg="Yellow",command=quit).pack()
            self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=650, bg='#afeeee')
            self.canvas.create_text(400, 30, fill="darkblue", font="Times 20 italic bold", text="Click the bubbles that are answers in the two times tables.")
            #Shows score at beinging of the game
            self.current_score = self.canvas.create_text(200, 60, fill="darkblue", font="Times 15 italic bold", text="Your score is: 0")
            self.canvas.pack()



        def make_bubbles(self):
            for each_no in range(1, 21):
                self.buttonclick += 1 #Newly added in attempt to hide button
                xval = random.randint(5, 765)
                yval = random.randint(5, 615)
                COLOURS = ('#00ff7f', '#ffff00', '#ee82ee', '#ff69b4', '#fff0f5') # CAPS represents a constant variable
                colour = random.choice(COLOURS) # This picks a colour randomly
                oval_id = self.canvas.create_oval(xval, yval, xval + 60, yval + 60,fill=colour, outline="#000000", width=5, tags="bubble")
                text_id = self.canvas.create_text(xval + 30, yval + 30, text=each_no, tags="bubble")
                self.canvas.tag_bind("bubble", "<Button-1>", lambda x: self.click(x))
                self.bubbles[oval_id] = (xval, yval, 0, 0, each_no, text_id) # add bubbles to dictionary
                if buttonclick == 2: #Newly added in attempt to hide button
                    showinfo("Oh No", "Sorry %s, but the game is already started" % self.name)

        def click(self, event):
            if self.canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
                item_uid = event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
                is_even = False
                try: # clicked oval
                    self.bubbles[item_uid]
                except KeyError: # clicked oval
                    for key, value in self.bubbles.iteritems():
                        if item_uid == value[5]: # comparing to text_id
                           if value[4] % 2 == 0:
                                is_even = True
                            self.canvas.delete(key) # deleting oval
                            self.canvas.delete(item_uid) # deleting text
                else:
                    if self.bubbles[item_uid][4] % 2 == 0:
                        is_even = True
                    self.canvas.delete(item_uid) # deleting oval
                    self.canvas.delete(self.bubbles[item_uid][5]) # deleting text

                if is_even:
                    self.score += 1
                else:
                    self.score -= 1
                    showinfo("Oh no!", "%s! You clicked the wrong bubble, please start again." % self.name)

                if self.score == 10:
                    #Tells user You won! if score is 10
                    showinfo("Winner", "You won %s!" % self.name)


            self.canvas.delete(self.current_score)
            #Shows updated score on canvas
            self.current_score = self.canvas.create_text(200, 60, fill="darkblue", font="Times 15 italic bold", text="Your score is: %s"%self.score)

        def bubble_move(self, root):
            for oval_id, (x, y, dx, dy, each_no, text_id) in self.bubbles.items():
                # update velocities and positions
                dx += random.randint(-1, 1)
                dy += random.randint(-1, 1)
                # dx and dy should not be too large
                dx, dy = max(-5, min(dx, 5)), max(-5, min(dy, 5))
                # bounce off walls
                if not 0 < x < 770:
                    dx = -dx
                if not 0 < y < 620:
                    dy = -dy
                # apply new velocities
                self.canvas.move(oval_id, dx, dy)
                self.canvas.move(text_id, dx, dy)
                self.bubbles[oval_id] = (x + dx, y + dy, dx, dy, each_no, text_id)
            # have mainloop repeat this after 100 ms
            root.after(100, self.bubble_move, root)

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        root = Tk()
        root.title("Welcome")
        Label(root, text="Welcome to Math bubbles, what is your name?").pack()
        name = Entry(root)
        name.pack()
        def submit(name, root):
        root.destroy()
        root = Tk()
        Label(root, text="Hello %s, press the Start button to begin.\n" % name).pack()
        BubbleFrame(root, name).bubble_move(root)
        Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda: submit(name.get(), root)).pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced IndentationError in line 103 and NameError in 39 (it is `self.buttonclick` not `buttonclick`). Next time check your code before posting.

Well, you invoke 20 buttonclicks each time you click on Start button and the value checking happens in the middle of the process.

I fixed the `make_bubbles` method for you abit.

```
def make_bubbles(self):
    self.buttonclick += 1 #Newly added in attempt to hide button
    if self.buttonclick == 2: #Newly added in attempt to hide button
        self.startbutton.configure(state="disabled")
        showinfo("Oh No", "Sorry %s, but the game is already started" % self.name)
        return
    for each_no in range(1, 21):
        ...
```

The logic to enable the button at the end of game is missing or perhaps no need at all. Maybe I would rather clear all bubbles and generate 20 new ones each time I click the Start button. Anyway, I recommend [this site](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) for tkinter programming.

There is some more things to fix here too. No more `iteritems()` in Python 3. Use `self.bubbles.items()` instead. Good luck!